# How do you make a dropdown selection return a cell text based on "yes" values in other cell?

Tags: excel, database, google-sheets, dropdown

I have the following data:
- **Article Excerpts** in Column D (D4:D1000)
- **Topics** in cells AE3:AU3
- **Either "Yes" or "No"** in every cell under the AC:AS columns (AE4:AU1000), based on whether the Article Excerpt in that row includes a keyword related to the header topic in each column.

I am looking for a way to create a Dropdown from which I could select a Topic and have all the Article Excerpts that are marked as "Yes" (in the relevant Topics column in the AE:AU range) show one under the other in the column next to the Dropdown.

**Example**:
I select Productivity (Topic) from the Dropdown in cell A4 and B4:B10 returns the 7 Article Excerpts that are marked as "Yes" under the Productivity header (AJ Column).

Hopefully that makes sense and is possible..

P.S. Looking for guidance for this to be used on either Excel or Sheets, doesn't matter which.

Edit: Sharing a link to a Google Sheet sample but again, guidance on either Excel of Sheets would be equally helpful. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCijce7F7H6zs-8VFzJX4A5Jy8IJ8focadj754XGIIg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show us some data sample?

Comment: @Harun24HR Sure, see here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tCijce7F7H6zs-8VFzJX4A5Jy8IJ8focadj754XGIIg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi ! **Could you please grant edit access so that I can make a copy of the sheet and in that copy test my solution?** You would basically be interested in using a **Data->Data Validation** for the dropdowns (selecting the range as the possible dropdown values) and then a series of ```IF``` conditions for displaying all the Article Excerpts.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Of course! Opened it for editing, I look forward to knowing if your solution worked.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right so just to not leave this open, I ended up solving this on my own by researching the web and combining a couple of formulas.

I created a new sheet (`"Search Tab"`) with a dropdown menu (data validation) in `A2`, that is based on the Topics columns headers. All the actual "raw" data is now in a separate sheet named `"All Data"`.

In the Search Tab, in Cell A5, I entered this formula:
`=filter('All Data'!D4:D1000,(offset('All Data'!AE3,1,match($A2,'All Data'!$AE$3:AU$3,0)-1,997,1))="yes")`

This basically filters the cells in column D that are in the same rows as cells that have the text "yes" in a specific Topics column (range `AE4:AU1000`) that matches the text selected in the dropdown menu in Cell `A2`.

It was very confusing to write so I can imagine it must be confusing to read, and not really sure how many people will come across such a need, but didn't want to leave this unresolved.